# Optional Binding, Capturing References and Closures [possible bug]

Tags: swift, closures, option-type

I have been trying to get myself acquainted with Swift, but I recently came across this peculiar problem involving Optional Bindings and capturing references within the context of Closures.

Given the following declarations (*code abbreviated for clarity; full code provided at the end*):

```
class Thing
{
      func giveNameIfSize() -> String? {
            /.../
      }
}

typealias IterationBlock = (Thing) -> Bool

class Iterable
{
     func iterate(block: IterationBlock) {
            /.../
     }
}
```

An `Iterable` object can store a collection of `Things` and can iterate through them using a closure. Now say we wanted to find the name of the `Thing` object that has a `size` property set up. We could do something like this:

```
var name: String?
iterable.iterate { (someThing) -> Bool in
    /* 
      Assigning the result of the giveNameIfSize() function to 
      a variable 'name' declared outside of the closure and
      captured by reference 
    */
    if name = someThing.giveNameIfSize() { 
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

However, the code above generates the following compiler error:

> Cannot assign to immutable value of type 'String?'

Curiously enough, the problem disappears when we use another variable in the optional binding:

```
iterable.iterate { (someThing) -> Bool in
    if var tempResult = someThing.giveNameIfSize() {
        name = tempResult
        return true
    }
    return false
} /* COMPILES AND RUNS */
```

The problem is also resolved if we assign a value to the externally declared variable `name` outside of the optional binding:

```
iterable.iterate { (someThing) -> Bool in
    name = someThing.giveNameIfSize()
    if name != nil {
        return true
    }
    return false
} /* ALSO COMPILES AND RUNS */
```

Full source code [here](https://github.com/BellAppLab/Closures).

*Obs.: Tested this code with Swift 1.2, not 2.0.*

**====**

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're receiving is a little misleading, but the underlying problem here is that you're trying to do something that Swift doesn't support. In Swift, you can't use the result of assignment in a condition.

That being said, both of your proposed alternative methods will work, although I tend to think that the first of the two is a little more Swifty.

Comment: I see what you mean and you are right. The error message has nothing to do with the Closure, but with the `if` statement itself. However, judging by the fact that `if var tempResult = someThing.giveNameIfSize() {` works, would it be possible to assume that Optional Bindings are optimized into something different than an `if` statement that evaluates an assignment?